# Removing Push notification alert if another device has responded to the alert

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push

I noticed a feature of iMessage that i'm interested in replicating. The problem is i'm not sure if it is possible using Apple's public API.

I notice that if you receive an iMessage, push notifications are displayed on all of your devices lock screens ( ex. iPhone, iPad ). However, once one of your devices views the new message, the push notification alert dissappears on all devices.

Is there a way to remove a push notification alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so since iOS 10, Apple has introduced a new notification framework: [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications).

With this, you now a tremendous amount of customization and also have the ability to remove/update presented notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not possible without using private APIs.

Answer (score -1):

Create two push notifications: one for displaying alert, second for hiding it. If one device has responded on displaying alert notification, then send hiding alert notification.

Comment: "Hiding alert notification"? How would you do that?

Comment: I assumed that much.  What would the contents of the "hiding" alert consist of (keys/values)? As far as i know, there is no key that indicates the removal of an alert.